# Codeblocks C++ Compiling Error on Codeblocks w/ GCC

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I have been writing c++ for a little while using Visual Studio on Windows, and I recently switched to Linux Mint, and installed Codeblocks to use as my C++ IDE.  I have written a very simple program, which I cannot get to compile:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

I have tried running this, and I get a console error message:

```
Executing: xterm -T Test -e /usr/bin/cb_console_runner LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:. /home/***/workspaces/cpp-workspace/Test/bin/Debug/Test  (in /home/***/workspaces/cpp-workspace/Test/.)
Process terminated with status -1 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
```

I have also tried running cc against my main.cpp file, and I get an error message saying:

```
/tmp/cc4RcEeE.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0xe): undefined reference to `std::cout'
main.cpp:(.text+0x13): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x1d): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::endl<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x28): undefined reference to `std::ostream::operator<<(std::ostream& (*)(std::ostream&))'
main.cpp:(.text+0x2f): undefined reference to `std::cin'
main.cpp:(.text+0x34): undefined reference to `std::istream::get()'
/tmp/cc4RcEeE.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
main.cpp:(.text+0x64): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::Init()'
main.cpp:(.text+0x79): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::~Init()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

**Additional Information:**

- I have installed GCC on my machine
- I installed Codeblocks using the Mint Software Manager

I have been researching this problem over the course of a week or so, and have been unable to get anything to work.  Any help getting this compile would be much appreciated!

**EDIT**
I have checked through my compiler settings according to the suggestions given, and they all appear correct. I've added a screenshot of my settings in case someone sees something...  Also, g++ is not listed as an option in the drop-down for compilers.
[My codeblocks settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sj6KC.png)

Comment: It looks like you are compiling and linking your code as C, not C++. In Code::Blocks Settings|Compiler|toolchain make sure you have g++ selected as your C++ compiler, and that you have created a C++ project.

Comment: Make sure you saved your file as a `cpp` file, not a `c` file. Also, you forgot the `std::` before the `endl`.

Answer (score 0):

`cc` builds C programs. That won't bring in the standard library for C++, hence the linker errors.

You want a C++ compiler, like the one you have already installed: `g++`.

Indeed, until you've built your program successfully, you won't be able to execute it.

This ought to be covered in your C++ book, which you can review now.